# ChartJs is not showing line color in different color

Tags: jquery, reactjs, typescript, charts, chart.js

I am currently working on a chart which is painting a graph with the help of chartjs. But now able to get the line color as expected.

My entire code are below. Am I missing anything?

```
import { Box, IconButton, Paper, Tooltip, Typography } from "@material-ui/core";
import {
  AddCircleOutline,
  KeyboardArrowLeft,
  KeyboardArrowRightOutlined,
  RemoveCircleOutline,
  RotateLeft,
} from "@material-ui/icons";
import React from "react";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Line } from "react-chartjs-2";
import { SignalStrengthMain, ISignalStrength } from "../../VSATGraphs/types";

const SignalStrength1 = ({ ssValue }: { ssValue: ISignalStrength[] }) => {
  const [serial, setSerial] = useState<string>();
  const [resolution, setResolution] = useState<number>(300);
  // Series Features
  const [SingleStrengthMax, setSingleStrengthMax] = useState(100);
  const [SingleStrengthMin, setSingleStrengthMin] = useState(100);

  // Series
  const [signals, setSignals] = useState<ISignalStrength[]>();
  const [timeLabels, setTimeLabels] = useState<string[][]>();

  // Series Paginator Controls
  const [length, setLength] = useState<number>();
  const minSliceLength = 5;
  const [sliceLength, setSliceLength] = useState(10);
  const [startPoint, setStartPoint] = useState<number>(0);
  useEffect(() => {
    // Perform this fetching at redux end
    //setBandwidth(vsatPerformace.bandwidth);
    console.log("---------set signals");
    setSignals(ssValue);
    console.log(ssValue);
    console.log("---------set signals");
    setResolution(300);
    setSerial(ssValue[0].modem);
    setTimeLabels(buildTimeLabels(ssValue.map((p) => p.timestamp)));
    setLength(ssValue.length);
    setSliceLength(ssValue.length);
    setSingleStrengthMax(Math.ceil(Math.max(...ssValue.map((el) => el.rssi))));
    setSingleStrengthMin(Math.min(...ssValue.map((el) => el.rssi)) - 10);
  }, []);
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("--------- signals---------------");
    console.log(signals);
    console.log("--------- signals-------------");
  }, []);
  return (
    <Paper
      style={{
        margin: "auto",
        width: "100%",
        padding: 10,
        paddingLeft: 0,
        paddingBottom: 5,
        paddingTop: 5,
        paddingRight: 10,
        display: "flex",
        flexDirection: "column",
        alignItems: "center",
        justifyContent: "center",
      }}
    >
      <Typography align="center" variant="subtitle2">
        RSSI Strength
      </Typography>
      <Box
        style={{
          overflowY: "scroll",
          position: "relative",
          width: "100%",
          outline: "none",
        }}
        onKeyDown={(e) => {
          switch (e.key) {
            case "ArrowRight":
              if (!(length - startPoint - 1 === sliceLength)) {
                setStartPoint(startPoint + 1);
              }
              break;

            case "ArrowLeft":
              if (!(startPoint === 0)) {
                setStartPoint(startPoint - 1);
              }
              break;

            case "ArrowUp":
              if (!(sliceLength <= minSliceLength)) {
                setSliceLength(sliceLength - 1);
              }
              break;

            case "ArrowDown":
              if (!(sliceLength >= length)) {
                setSliceLength(sliceLength + 1);
              }
              break;
            case "Escape":
              if (!(sliceLength >= length)) {
                setSliceLength(length);
                setStartPoint(0);
              }
              break;

            default:
              break;
          }
        }}
        tabIndex={-1}
      >
        {signals ? (
          <Line
            height={350}
            data={{
              labels: timeLabels
                ? timeLabels.slice(startPoint, startPoint + sliceLength)
                : null,
              datasets: [
                {
                  //borderColor: "#0178D4",
                  borderColor: getColorforPerformance(signals.length, signals),
                  borderJoinStyle: "miter",
                  borderCapStyle: "butt",
                  //backgroundColor: "#0178D4",
                  backgroundColor: getColorforPerformance(
                    signals.length,
                    signals
                  ),
                  borderDash: [],
                  borderDashOffset: 0.0,
                  fill: false,
                  borderWidth: "2",
                  // lineTension: 0,
                  label: "rssi",
                  //pointBorderColor: "#0178D4",
                  pointBorderColor: getColorforPerformance(
                    signals.length,
                    signals
                  ),
                  //pointBackgroundColor:"#fff"
                  pointBackgroundColor: getColorforPerformance(
                    signals.length,
                    signals
                  ),
                  pointBorderWidth: 1,
                  pointHoverRadius: 5,
                  pointHoverBackgroundColor: getColorforPerformance(
                    signals.length,
                    signals
                  ),
                  //pointHoverBackgroundColor: "#0178D4",
                  //pointHoverBorderColor: "#0178D4",
                  pointHoverBorderColor: getColorforPerformance(
                    signals.length,
                    signals
                  ),
                  pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
                  pointRadius: 0,
                  pointHitRadius: 10,
                  data: signals
                    ? signals
                        .slice(startPoint, startPoint + sliceLength)
                        .map((p) => p.rssi)
                    : null,
                },
              ],
            }}
            options={{
              legend: {
                display: true,
                position: "top",
                labels: {
                  boxWidth: 50,
                  fontColor: "black",
                },
              },
              line: {
                borderColor: "#F85F73",
              },
              maintainAspectRatio: false,
              responsive: true,
              scales: {
                yAxes: [
                  {
                    scaleLabel: {
                      display: true,
                      labelString: "Signal(dBm)",
                    },
                    ticks: {
                      min: SingleStrengthMin,
                      stepSize: 10,
                      max: SingleStrengthMax,
                    },
                  },
                ],
                xAxes: [
                  {
                    scaleLabel: {
                      display: true,
                      labelString: `Format: UTC | 24 Hours | dd/mm/yy - Resolution: ${resolution} Seconds`,
                    },
                    gridLines: {
                      display: false,
                    },
                  },
                ],
              },
              animation: {
                duration: 0,
              },
            }}
          />
        ) : null}

        {sliceLength !== length
          ? [
              <Tooltip key="left" title="Move Left (Keyboard Arrow Left)">
                <IconButton
                  color="primary"
                  size="small"
                  style={{
                    position: "absolute",
                    top: "calc(50% - 20px)",
                    left: 60,
                  }}
                  disabled={startPoint === 0}
                  onClick={() => setStartPoint(startPoint - 1)}
                >
                  <KeyboardArrowLeft />
                </IconButton>
              </Tooltip>,
              <Tooltip key="right" title="Move Right (Keyboard Arrow Right)">
                <IconButton
                  color="primary"
                  size="small"
                  style={{
                    position: "absolute",
                    top: "calc(50% - 20px)",
                    right: 10,
                  }}
                  disabled={length - startPoint - 1 === sliceLength}
                  onClick={() => setStartPoint(startPoint + 1)}
                >
                  <KeyboardArrowRightOutlined />
                </IconButton>
              </Tooltip>,
            ]
          : null}

        <Box
          style={{
            position: "absolute",
            top: 5,
            right: 10,
          }}
        >
          <Tooltip title="Zoom In (Keyboard Arrow Up)">
            <span>
              <IconButton
                size="small"
                color="primary"
                disabled={sliceLength <= minSliceLength}
                onClick={() => setSliceLength(sliceLength - 1)}
              >
                <AddCircleOutline fontSize="small" />
              </IconButton>
            </span>
          </Tooltip>

          <Tooltip title="Zoom Out (Keyboard Arrow Down)">
            <span>
              <IconButton
                size="small"
                color="primary"
                disabled={sliceLength >= length}
                onClick={() => setSliceLength(sliceLength + 1)}
              >
                <RemoveCircleOutline fontSize="small" />
              </IconButton>
            </span>
          </Tooltip>

          <Tooltip title="Reset (Esc)">
            <span>
              <IconButton
                size="small"
                color="primary"
                disabled={sliceLength === length}
                onClick={() => setSliceLength(length)}
              >
                <RotateLeft fontSize="small" />
              </IconButton>
            </span>
          </Tooltip>
        </Box>
      </Box>
    </Paper>
  );
};

export default SignalStrength1;

const buildTimeLabels = (series: number[]) => {
  console.log("====series=====");
  console.log(series);
  console.log("====series=====");
  const _fullDateFlags = [];

  series.forEach((el, idx) => {
    _fullDateFlags.push(
      new Date(el).getUTCHours() < new Date(series[idx - 1]).getUTCHours() ||
        idx === 0 ||
        idx === series.length - 1
    );
  });

  const getDate = (ts: number) => {
    const date = new Date(ts * 1000);
    return `${date.getUTCDate()}/${date.getUTCMonth() +
      1}/${date.getUTCFullYear()}`;
  };

  const getTime = (ts: number) => {
    const date = new Date(ts * 1000);
    return `${padTo2Digits(date.getUTCHours())}:${padTo2Digits(
      date.getUTCMinutes()
    )}`;
  };

  const getFull = (ts: number) => [`${getTime(ts)}`, `${getDate(ts)}`];

  const _series = _fullDateFlags.map((el, idx) => {
    if (el) {
      return getFull(series[idx]);
    } else {
      return [getTime(series[idx]), " "];
    }
  });

  return _series;
};
const getColorforPerformance = (count: number, signals) => {
  var data = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    if (signals[i].rssi >= 20) data.push(getColors(0));
    else if (signals[i].rssi > 13 && signals[i].rssi < 20)
      data.push(getColors(3));
    else if (signals[i].rssi > 0 && signals[i].rssi < 13)
      data.push(getColors(2));
    else data.push(getColors(1));
  }
  return data;
};

function padTo2Digits(number) {
  return number >= 10 ? number + "" : "0" + number;
}

function getColors(code: number): any {
  let color = "#";
  if (code === 1) {
    color += "FF0000";
  } else if (code === 2) {
    color += "FFFF00";
  } else if (code === 3) {
    color += "00FF00";
  } else {
    color += "006400";
  }
  return color;
}
```

and one more thing I have created the time label but it's not showing in proper format. Ideally once my graph will start with new 00.01 time then date+time should be displayed but it's not.

[image: Image of my chart]

Comment: why jquery tag?

Comment: because may be anyone can help me with jquery ?

Comment: but are you using jquery in the question? it is not appropiate to include tags in questions that involve potential help, but the ones that actually are involved in the question and the tech stack being used

Comment: also if you could add the code as a reproducible snippet, the potential helper could play around with the code to help you out ;)